# Select list - after selection scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-forms

I got a select list, when i am trying to select one option either in last or middle it’s taking me to top of the list. Ui is on angular 5. Does anyone have idea he to deal with it. I have been reading lot of articles an blogs but nothing’s helping me out.

Comment: Can you put some code into this question?

Comment: <select id="lb" style="width:130px; height:150px;" multiple="multiple">  
    <option value="0">item number 0</option>
    <option value="1">item number 1</option>
    <option value="2">item number 2</option>
    <option value="3">item number 3</option>
    <option value="4">item number 4</option>
    <option value="5">item number 5</option>
    <option value="6">item number 6</option>
    <option value="7">item number 7</option>
    <option value="8">item number 8</option>
    <option value="9">item number 9</option>
 </select>
its just select list with no dropdown.

Comment: its a multiselect.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to select an item using your mouse? Or via binding [(ngModel)] on init or something? Does it only happen when you select the middle / bottom item or any item? It would be helpful to include a more complete sample to help illustrate your problem. You can edit your original question to include code (Ctrl + K to insert code block). Or - you could quickly reproduce it on StackBlitz and post a link to that.

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz example